# Bitmap to uri conversion android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, uri

how to get uri from Bitmap after cropping image was selected from gallery

i tried this

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

but uri = null

i want to get uri from this

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            performCrop(imageUri);
            Log.e(TAG, "image before crop:" + imageUri);

        }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PIC_CROP ){
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            getImageUri(this,selectedBitmap);
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
            Log.e(TAG, "image before crop:" + ImageUri);
```

log image before crop=null

---- UPDATE  CROPPING----

```
   private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
try {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    // indicate image type and Uri
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    // set crop properties here
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
    // indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    // indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
    // retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
}
// respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    // display an error message
    String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing you are selecting an image from your gallery.

perquisites:

- Permissions in manifest to read/write data
- Validation of permissions and handle no permissions granted case
- Request code declared:

  ```
  public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1050;
  ```

(1) 
Open image selector activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

In Activity:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

In Fragment:

```
fragment.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

(2) retrieving image from selection:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null ){

    switch(requestCode){

        case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
            //get filepath from the result of image selection
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            //Start activity for result for crop for selected image
            startCropActivity(filePath);
            break;

        case PIC_CROP:
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            //do whatever with the bitmap of the image
            break;

            }
        }
}
```

Start Crop activity as so:

```
private void startCropActivity(Uri filePath){
    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(filePath, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);

    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not crop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: @OsamahM I have updated my answer...the result from cropping produces a bit map of the cropped image..up to you what you want to do.. do you want to save the image? or set it as an image view ect.

Comment: @OsamahM do the logs say anything about strict mode?

Comment: i need to save image as temp and get the uri , after cropping need to add the image to the app , see here how i am adding the image to the app without cropping just selecting from gallery`Uri ImageUri = data.getData(); getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(ImageUri), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            stickers.addSticker(ImageUri, this);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());`
i need this to work also after cropping , so maybe need to save image first to get uri.    @haider-malik

Comment: can you please help me fix this @haider-malik